# Load JS only on specific content_type node creation

Tags: nodes, 6, javascript

Drupal 6. What is the proper way to execute `drupal_add_js` only when specific content_type is being created?

I have some jQuery code that needs to execute only to control some form elements in a specific content_type creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to write a simple module where you hook into the page you need and add [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6)

e.g. when you create a content type the form `node_type_form` is being called. so you have to hook into the form with

```
/**
 * implimentation of hook_form_alter()
 */
yourmodulename_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });','inline');
}
```

I asume you need to add a JS to a content_type being **viewed**. in this case you will need to use `hook_view()` :

```
/**
 * implimentation of hook_view()
 */
yourmodulename_view($node) {
    if ($node->type == "your_type") {
        drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });','inline');
    }
}
```

**Update:**

of course you can modify your `template.php` in the theme directory as well. remember that the theme for administration is different than the site theme by default. be aware which template.php file you are changing.

Comment: Thank you! Does the module need to have the same name as the content type?

Comment: +1 anonym-developer: what if it's added directly to the node-type.tpl.php file using drupal_add_js? would that be a wrong way of implementing it?

Comment: @djdy: no, name it like you want and place in the sites/all/modules/_custom folder. I always have a `mysettings` module to set those things.

Comment: @zarsiwala, its not the right way. you can put it in the `template.php`, probably the easier way, but never in the template file. image what happens if you list 5 different nodes in a view: your JS snipped/file will be parsed 5 times because the node.tpl.php is being parsed 5 times.

Comment: @anonym-developer oh okay, thanks so much. I always wondered about this.